# How to make Input.Password eye suffix to white in antd vite?

Tags: tailwind-css, antd

I want to make an input password with eye suffix is white like below:
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBuzW.png)

Currently, this is the result of my code:
[What I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnhzZ.png)

I use antd on ReactJS vite with tailwindcss, here is the code of the Input.Password:

```
<Input.Password
  placeholder="Password"
  bordered={false}
  prefix={<LockOutlined />}
  classNames={{
  input: "text-gray-200 placeholder-gray-400",
  affixWrapper: "text-gray-200",
  }}
/>
```

affixWrapper should change the style of the prefix and the suffix of an input element (I try to put suffix in basic input and worked). But in the Input.Password, the suffix (eye icon) style is not change. Anyone got solution?